# How to set system property for xsbt-web-plugin's jetty()?

Tags: sbt, logback, xsbt-web-plugin

I've migrated my project to 0.13.5 and started using the [xsbt-web-plugin](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin).

I'd like to configure logback to be using a configuration file outside the classpath which is set by a system property `logback.configurationFile` (so I can keep the logconfig outside the war file).

Previously I would simply set:

```
System.setProperty("logback.configurationFile", "/some/path/logback.xml")
```

inside the `project/build.scala` and logback would pick it up.

However, after upgrading sbt to 0.13.5 and migrating to the xsbt-web-plugin system properties set in sbt don't seem to be available at runtime(jetty).

I've tried setting system properties in different ways, also by passing it along using the `-D` flag when starting sbt.

On the sbt console I can see the property:

```
eval sys.props("logback.configurationFile")
[info] ans: String = /some/path/logback.xml
```

But it's not available inside the webapp.

Any ideas on how to set system properties to be available inside the webapp?

I've tried both `jetty()` and `tomcat()`. Same behaviour.

**Update:**
I ended up with:

```
jetty(options = new ForkOptions(runJVMOptions = Seq("-Dlogback.configurationFile=/some/path/logback.xml")))
```

that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `javaOptions in container += "-Dlogback.configurationFile=/some/path/logback.xml"` as described in [Set forked JVM options](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin#set-forked-jvm-options).

`javaOptions` alone (without `in container`) should work, too, as could be seen in `inspect actual` under `Dependencies` and `Delegates`:

```
[play-new-app] $ inspect actual container:javaOptions
[info] Task: scala.collection.Seq[java.lang.String]
[info] Description:
[info]  Options passed to a new JVM when forking.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/play-new-app/}root/container:javaOptions
[info] Defined at:
[info]  /Users/jacek/sandbox/play-new-app/build.sbt:26
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  */*:javaOptions
[info] Delegates:
[info]  container:javaOptions
[info]  *:javaOptions
[info]  {.}/container:javaOptions
[info]  {.}/*:javaOptions
[info]  */container:javaOptions
[info]  */*:javaOptions
[info] Related:
[info]  */*:javaOptions
```

Comment: I tried setting the javaOptions in container, but it didn't work somehow, but you got me thinking in the right direction.